# Add handlers dynamically to dynamically created menu

Tags: google-apps-script

This code creates a menu/sub menu via the arrays taken from a sheet (GApps)

```
    // get globals
    var arrayMenu = globals.mpMenuItems;
    var arraySubMenu = globals.mpSubMenuItems;

    // create menu
    var menuBar = app.createMenuBar();
    var handler = app.createServerHandler();

    // add structure to menu
    for(var k=0; k<arrayMenu.length; k++) {
      menuBar.addItem(arrayMenu[k], this[arrayMenu[k][k]] = app.createMenuBar(true));
      for(var j=0; j<arraySubMenu[k].length; j++) {
        this[arrayMenu[k][k]].addItem(arraySubMenu[k][j], **handler**)
          .addSeparator(app.createMenuItemSeparator());
      }
      menuBar.addSeparator(app.createMenuItemSeparator());
    } 
    return menuBar;
```

Can anybody of you show me the way, how I can add the **handlers** dynamically as well? I've used the GWT code example as a guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create handlers using UiInstance's [createServerHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance#createServerHandler)() and [createClientHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance#createClientHandler)() methods.

Comment: Hi Erik, I need the handler to be created at the **handler** position, so that each sub menu item gets a specific handler. Somehow it isn't meant to be created over there, but only referenced. Do you get my drift? Jacob Jan

Comment: No, I don't understand. You could create a server handler in the loop as well, but it will need to point to a function that already exists.

Comment: UiInstance was deprecated December, 2014, and now I find myself wanting to do a similar thing to the original question.