# SelectedItem from menuBar

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script, menubar

I've got two questions:

1. How to get a selectedItem on the sub menu as described in reference 1 (see also refenrence 2), workable in Google apps script
2. Is reference 3 related to this question? If yes, please star so that it might get some attention !!

=====

1. [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549869/add-handlers-dynamically-to-dynamically-created-menu)
2. [Reference to Vaadin (GWT)](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.menubar.html)
3. [Issue 1413](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1413)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a different server handler for each item, with each one pointing to a different callback function.

Comment: It's worked the way you proposed. Professional blindness.... I was aiming for selection handlers i guess. Issue 1413 stands!