# How I create a SubMenu whit google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to know how create a simple menu with 2 menu items(**A** and **B**): the first one(A) contains 1 item (**A1**),the second one(B), contains 3 items inside(**B1,B2,B3**)

I can create an example but always fail:

**CODE**

```
      var handler = app.createServerHandler();
     //Create menu bar
      var menuBar = app.createMenuBar(true);

      var data =  ss.getSheets()[LOG_SHEET_INDEX].getDataRange().getValues();

      var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
      for(var row = 1; row < lastRow; row++){
        var id_menu =1;
        if(data[row][0]==0){
          var nivel = data[row][1];
          var menuItem = app.createMenuItem(data[row][2], handler);

          var separator = app.createMenuItemSeparator();
          menuBar.addSeparator(separator);
          var subMenu = app.createMenuBar(true).setId("subMenu"+nivel);
          for(var i = 1; i< lastRow; i++){
            if(data[i][0]==nivel){
              var sm = app.getElementById("subMenu"+nivel)
              this[sm.addItem(data[row][2], handler)];
            }

          }menuItem.setSubMenu(sm);

        }menuBar.addItem(data[row][2], app.createMenuBar(true));

      }


      app.add(menuBar);
```

**RESULT**

[image: fail]

and i need something like (hidding A1,B1,B2,B3 : showing when focus A|B):

```
    ____
    A
        A1
    ____
    B
        B1
        B2
        B3
```

**THIS IS MY SPREAD:**

[image: fail2]

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, as Serge pointed out my prev. answer is wrong. Meanwhile I found out, what the real reason is: 
The MenuItem having the submenu must not have a handler:

```
 var menuBar=app.createMenuBar();
 var subb1=app.createMenuBar(true);
 subb1.addItem (app.createMenuItem("S1", handler1));
 subb1.addItem (app.createMenuItem("S2", handler2));
 var mi1=app.createMenuItem("X1", null); // passing null and not a handler makes submenu work...
 mi1.setSubMenu(subb1);
 menuBar.addItem(mi1);
 app.add(menuBar);
```

Comment: Nice digging ! have you tried to add a handler separately ? A menu without handler is not very useful is it ?

Comment: If you add a handler to the MenuItem hosting the submenu, then when you click it, your handler will be called, and the submenu wont open. So somehow in the code there must be a decision "if hander, then call it else if there is a submenu then show it." So the submenu gets hidden by the handler i think.

Comment: You're right, the handler can be added to the submenu items... it doesn't make sense to have a handler at the first level (I didn't think about it accurately enough ;-)

Comment: Could you help me to find a solution?

Comment: he got submenus:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549869/add-handlers-dynamically-to-dynamically-created-menu

Answer (score 1):

I done it but I have a problem with handers which can't be used(both serverhandle and clienthandler) becouse the parameter 'e' is undefined or void: (Also a problem with MenuItemID)

- I need to know which button is presed knowing 'e' and dont know whats wrong.

  ```
  do get(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var menu = menuBar();
  var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setId("Panel");
  var horizontalPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("horizontalPanel");
  var verticalPanelDoc = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("verticalPanelDoc");
  var verticalPanelMenu = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("verticalPanelMenu");
  var scrollPanelDoc = app.createScrollPanel().setId("scrollPanelDoc").setSize('1000', '600');

  verticalPanelMenu.add(menu);
  verticalPanelDoc.add(scrollPanelDoc);
  horizontalPanel.add(verticalPanelMenu);
  horizontalPanel.add(verticalPanelDoc);

  panel.add(horizontalPanel)
  app.add(panel);

  return app;
  }


  function show(e){

    var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openById(TABLA_MENU);
    //**testing 'e' = undefined or void**
    var e_source = e.parameter.source;
    ss.getSheetByName("menu").getRange("B"+6).setValue(e_source);
    ss.getSheetByName("menu").getRange("C"+6).setValue(e);
    //**result in cells :   e_source = undefined   e = {parameter={}}**

    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var panel = app.getElementById("Panel");
    var verticalPanelDoc = app.getElementById("verticalPanelDoc");
    var horizontalPanel = app.getElementById("horizontalPanel");
    var scrollPanelDoc = app.getElementById("scrollPanelDoc");
    verticalPanelDoc.clear();
    verticalPanelDoc.remove(scrollPanelDoc);

    //**this will depend of 'e' **

    var panelToShow = app.createCaptionPanel().setTitle("Show").setText("Show");
    //
    var label = app.createLabel().setText("Works!");
    panelToShow.add(label);
    verticalPanelDoc.add(panelToShow);


    return app;
  };

  function menuBar(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TABLA_MENU);
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var absolutePanel = app.getElementById("absolutePanel");
    var verticalPanelMenu = app.getElementById("verticalPanelMenu");
    var horizontalPanel = app.getElementById("horizontalPanel");

    var option_menu = app.getElementById("option_menu");

    var arrayMenu = ss.getSheetByName("menu").getDataRange().getValues();
    var arraySubMenu =ss.getSheetByName("submenu").getDataRange().getValues();
    var arrayEnlacesSubMenu =ss.getSheetByName("enlaces").getDataRange().getValues();
    var test1 = arraySubMenu[1][1];//A1
    var test2 = arrayMenu[1];//A
    var test3 = arrayEnlacesSubMenu[1][1]
    // **create menu**
    var menuBar = app.createMenuBar(true).setAnimationEnabled(true);

    var handler = app.createServerHandler("show")
    .addCallbackElement(verticalPanelMenu)
    .addCallbackElement(horizontalPanel)
    .addCallbackElement(absolutePanel);

    // **add structure to menu**
    for(var k=1; k<arrayMenu.length; k++) {

      menuBar.addItem(arrayMenu[k][1], arrayMenu[k][1] = app.createMenuBar(true).setWidth("100%")).setWidth("100%");

      for(var j=1; j<arraySubMenu[k].length; j++){
        if(arraySubMenu[k][j]!=''){
          var enlace = arrayEnlacesSubMenu[j][1].toString();

          var a = arrayMenu[k][1];
          var b = arraySubMenu[k][j];
          //var c = this[arrayMenu[k][1]].addItem(arraySubMenu[k][j],handler).addSeparator(app.createMenuItemSeparator())
          arrayMenu[k][1].addItem(arraySubMenu[k][j],handler).setId("1"+arraySubMenu[k][j])).addSeparator(app.createMenuItemSeparator());
          //**THIS ID nither set the ID* show in navigator ID = ... class="gwt-MenuItem" id="gwt-uid-18" role="menuitem" aria-hasp....pan="1">Publicaciones 2012</td>
        }
      }
      menuBar.addSeparator(app.createMenuItemSeparator());
    } 
    return menuBar;
  };
  ```

**menuSpreadsheet**

[image: menu1]

**submenuSpreadsheet**

[image]

Comment: done it! 

I only failed getting e so in .addCallBackElement() instead of the name of my panel i wrote:

addCallbackElement(app.createHidden("id_option", arraySubMenu[k][j]).setId("id_option")))

and later get the id with e.parameterid_option (so 'e' is not void)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't have it (yet): http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=317

Comment: This references an enhancement request for spreadsheet menus... the question is about UI menus...

Comment: From what do you derive that? In the isue is written "Users request the ability to have custom menus and sub-menus (e.g. menu entries with children.)". And thisone here, although going thru a spreadsheet to find out which menuitems to add, adds the menu-items at the UI-Level.

Comment: First of all issue 317 was submitted in 2010 and there where no UiApp in 2010 ! And the question is clearly about menus in UiApp (see the code : app.getElementById(...) ) To me there is not any doubt about that.

Comment: see also [issue 1474](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1474) that has been merged in 317

Comment: You are right. For me it was evident that it must be the reason why it does not work, because I tried out to implement a sample and it did not work either. But now I know why my sample (and this one too) does not work, see next answer.